# Force thread to context switch

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, thread-sleep

I have a function `foo` in which I want to create and start a thread but delay it running to completion until `foo` returns.

I have achieved this by introducing a delay into the new thread, using a call to `sleep`, effectively (I think) causing a context switch.

```
String foo()
{
    // do some stuff

    Runnable task1 = () -> 
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);

        // do some stuff
    };

    // start the thread
    new Thread(task1).start();

    return "bar";
}
```

It seems to work - i.e. `foo` always returns before `task1` does its stuff.

Is the use of `sleep` the correct way to do this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I think a better way to do this is to use `priority`

Comment: While your solution *seems to work* you don't have any guarantees it actually does. There could be another thread demanding cpu time before the `return` statement executes (for example a unexpected lengthy garbage collection) and then the scheduler gives priority back to your task. It is unlikely but totally in the realm of possibilities. The solution is to not start your thread if it needs initialization done beforehand until the initialization is done.

Comment: @Ben Please can you elaborate.

Comment: What shall I elaborate? When you start threads you are giving the order of execution in the hands of the scheduler that decides when which thread gets to do things. Adding `sleeps` in there to "give time for other threads to catch up" is a solution that might work in some cases or maybe even most of the time but it gives you no guarantees whatsoever.

Comment: No guaranteee it will work always. Maybe you would want to start the thread after the foo() method call. You can construct the thread inside the method and make it return a reference to it. eg: foo().start();

Comment: @Ben The new thread does not need initialisation beforehand. It just needs to not complete before `foo` returns.

Comment: If it's not supposed to complete before foo returns then start if after foo returns. Alternatively have it `wait` before completion and call `notify` on it to stop the wait.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(n)` only guarantees that the calling thread will be blocked for _n_ milliseconds. It can _not_ guarantee that some other thread won't be blocked by more than _n_ milliseconds (e.g., because of heavy demand for CPU time by other, unrelated processes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Semaphore` to control it all properly.

```
String foo() {
    Semaphore waitUntilWeReturn = new Semaphore(-1);
    Runnable task1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            awaitPermissionToProceed();
            // do some stuff

        }

        private void awaitPermissionToProceed() {
            try {
                waitUntilWeReturn.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    // start the thread
    new Thread(task1).start();

    waitUntilWeReturn.release();
    return "bar";
}
```

Comment: Could the context be switched immediately to the new thread when `release` is called, and it run to completion before `foo` returns?

Comment: @ksl - Yes, under almost incredible circumstances - but much much more unlikely than a simple `Thread.sleep`. There is a **very** short window in which that could happen (just a few instructions).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, Re, "a _very_ short window." In my experience, when you've taken steps to make sure that some undesirable thing _almost never_ happens, then what you've really done is, you've ensured that if and when it eventually _does_ happen, it will happen in some important customer's production system instead of happening in your own test harness.

Comment: @ksl, OldCurmudgeon's answer does not release the semaphore until after the `foo()` function has done everything that it is going to do.  Why does it matter whether the `foo()` call has actually returned or not?  (i.e., what bad thing could happen if `...do some stuff...` starts to execute before `foo()` returns?)

Comment: @jameslarge It's a simplified example. It *does* matter than `foo()` returns first.

Comment: @ksl, Yes, you said in your original question that you did not want the `do some stuff` to start until after `foo()` returned. I'm asking why. The reason I'm asking is, I can't see any reason for it when I look at your example. I think you have _over_ simplified it. If it's important not to start the `do some stuff` until after `foo()` returns, then the reason must be something that happens at the call site. You haven't showed us the call site. You probably won't get any satisfactory answer if you can't show the code that matters (or some sanitized proxy for it).